# Is there any way to find who define / where a particular Spring Bean is defined?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

We have a large Spring project with dependencies coming from many different internal libraries.  We have a number of conflicts with the same bean being defined more than once.

We don't want to enable beans override configuration property.  So, need to know who define these beans and where they are defined?

Comment: Generally when you get the exception it also tells you where the offending bean is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I had luck adding a print statement [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6.0.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#L1002) in 6.0.9. Just:

`System.out.println("DefaultListableBeanFactory#registerBeanDefinition Registering: " + beanName);`

I could easily deduce where to look from the AutoConfiguration class that came right before the bean I was searching for. If you want, you can add a stack trace print out there as well. For me, that led me [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6.0.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L273). I don't know how to configure spring logging so I had to replicate that logging statement to System.out. Gives me a little more detail than my first print statement.

Of course, you have to clone and build the spring-beans and spring-context projects on your own and use the resulting jars. Or just turn on that trace logging.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA you can search for beans with Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N.